# How to get hovered element in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to get `hovered element` in html tables.

When I get `hovered id`I can change its classes. I've found `jQuery(":hover")` is useful in such case..

Are there any ways to implement it?

Thanks

```js
jQuery(":hover")   ?
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="4">4</td>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I highly recommend you do **not** use Javascript for this, and if you have to, use the normal DOM API, not jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `hover` event to the table `tds`.

```js
$('table td').hover(function() {
  const id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1">1</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>
    <td id="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">4</td>
    <td id="5">5</td>
    <td id="6">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">7</td>
    <td id="8">8</td>
    <td id="9">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean adding hover *event* using [**`.hover()`**](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```js
$('table tr td').hover(function(){
  console.clear(); //clear the previous log
  console.log(this.id);
  $(this).css({color: '#fff', backgroundColor: 'blue'});
});
```

```css
td{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1">1</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>
    <td id="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">4</td>
    <td id="5">5</td>
    <td id="6">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">7</td>
    <td id="8">8</td>
    <td id="9">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also pass second event handler function to perform some task when `mouseleave`:

```js
$('table tr td').hover(function(){
  console.clear(); //clear the previous log
  console.log(this.id);
  $(this).css({color: '#fff', backgroundColor: 'blue'});
}, function(){
  $(this).css({color: '#000', backgroundColor: '#fff'});
});
```

```css
td{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1">1</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>
    <td id="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">4</td>
    <td id="5">5</td>
    <td id="6">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">7</td>
    <td id="8">8</td>
    <td id="9">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to achieve is change the styling when an element is hovered, you definitely should **not** use Javascript for that. Simple CSS will do, and is faster by some orders of magnitude.

```css
td[id]:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1">1</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>
    <td id="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">4</td>
    <td id="5">5</td>
    <td id="6">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">7</td>
    <td id="8">8</td>
    <td id="9">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If for whatever reason you must use Javascript, this is very easy to achieve without any third party library.

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id) { // only log if it actually has an id
    console.log(event.target.id);
    event.target.classList.add('active');
  }
})

document.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id) { // only log if it actually has an id
    console.log(event.target.id);
    event.target.classList.remove('active');
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1">1</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>
    <td id="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">4</td>
    <td id="5">5</td>
    <td id="6">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">7</td>
    <td id="8">8</td>
    <td id="9">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**catch id on `mouseover` and reset it on `mouseout`**

css is only for demo *you can ignore it*

```js
$('table td').on('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
  let hoverId = $('table td:hover').attr('id');
    $('#HoveredId').html((hoverId ? 'hovered id = ' + hoverId : ''));
});
```

```css
#HoveredId {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px;
}
table td{
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
background: #000;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1">1</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>
    <td id="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">4</td>
    <td id="5">5</td>
    <td id="6">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">7</td>
    <td id="8">8</td>
    <td id="9">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="HoveredId"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a hard time understanding what you're asking, but you can add `hover` listeners to elements like this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$("td").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("red");
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

However if you're simply trying to change styles on hover, you should just use pure CSS like this:

```css
td:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```